# Is "javascript" a reserved word in mvc's querystring?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, routes, query-string

I'm debugging an old asp.net application, which tries to open a page inside a popup window. The url is created inside a piece of js code, this querystring (**H7.01 & hew asd !! $%^&*()!_++ -- <script language='javascript' ;> alert("newcode') ;</script ;get; est hufff**) is passed, but .net framework keeps crashing whenever it finds the words "javasctipt" or "script" in it. Are these reserved words in .net's routing security ? ... if I remove those words, the popup opens smoothly. I'm encoding the whole querystring before being passed (encodeURIComponent).

-ty,

Answer (score 0):

After a closer look at the exception, it seems this is just a normal framework validation process of inputs, [explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/request-validation).

Error Message :System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (checkedItem="... language='javascript'...").
at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_QueryString()
at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)